# How to test when bean is using a custom Lombok Builder

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

The following code works where my bean is using Lombok Builder annotations with a custom builder.

I am having issues with testing when I want to create this bean with values.
I can no longer use Setters (intentional) and can't just use .builder() due to the custom builder.

My question is, how do I create this bean in my tests? Note that I do want to use a builder and not looking to use Lombok's @Value annotation. The custom builder is necessary to work with Jackson.

One possibility I can think of is to add a constructor inside the custom builder which I hopefully don't need to do just for the sake of testing.

Please advice. Thanks.

Working Bean setup.

```
@Getter
@JsonDeserialize(builder = MyData.MyDataBuilder.class)
@Builder(builderClassName = "MyDataBuilder", toBuilder = true)
public class MyData {
    @JsonProperty("some_key")
    private String skey;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    // needed to work with Jackson
    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    static class MyDataBuilder {}
}
```

Test trying to create the Object. Following won't work as mentioned above.

```
MyData.builder()
    .skey("12345")
    .name("some_name")
    .build();
```

or

```
MyData myData = new MyData();
myData.skey("12345");
myData.name("some_name");
```

Comment: Why doesn't using the `builder()` approach work? Are you testing from a different package? Then make your builder class `public`.

Comment: @JanRieke Yes, testis from a different package. It would work if I make the MyDataBuilder public. But again, making a class public for the sake of testing. Not sure if that is ideal. That is my current solution if no other option. Edit: Read you mentioning the same.Ya thats where I am leaning on currently.

Comment: If the class and constructor are public, then I don't see a compelling reason why the builder class should not be. I mean if you add a builder, that should be the preferred way of instantiation, so you should typically make it as visible as the class. If you don't want your class to be instantiated elsewhere, then your test is also in the wrong package.

Comment: @JanRieke Thats a fair point. I will make it public. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the builder class to have any access level you want. Lombok makes it `public` by default if you don't customize it.

If the class itself and at least one constructor are `public`, it is possible to create instances from everywhere (not just the same package). But then there is no reason in most cases why the builder class should not be `public`, too: If the builder pattern is beneficial in its package, it will probably also be beneficial everywhere else.

If you don't want your class to be instantiated in other packages, then the builder should not be `public` (and also no constructor). However, then your test is also somehow flawed or in the wrong package.

So either make the custom builder class `public`, or change your test.